# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text" is not working

Tags: 11.10, startup, text-mode

I am trying to make Ubuntu run in text mode only as I want to use it as local server. I searched and found that I should edit `/etc/default/grub` and replace `quiet splash` with `text` then run `update-grub`, but nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, simply run the following in your terminal

```
echo 'manual' | sudo tee /etc/init/lightdm.override
sudo update-grub
```

Ref. to the [following topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1873309&page=2), Ubuntu 11.10 is using lightdm not gdm :